# HTMLHelper link() added unintended path

Tags: cakephp

I believe this is very simple question. Maybe that's why I can't find it on Google.

When I do this inside `View/Product/view.ctp`

```
echo $this->Html->link('Download PDF', 'app/files/product/1/manual.pdf');
```

The resulting URL is like this:

```
app/products/app/files/product/1/manual.pdf
```

It automatically added `app/products` since this is inside Product's view.

How to nullify that automatic addition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying a *relative* url, causing your browser to *append* the url to the current url.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Download PDF', '/app/files/product/1/manual.pdf');
```

(note the leading slash `/`)

Should result in a link to http://example.com/app/files/product/1/manual.pdf

Comment: Thanks, the solution is so simple

Comment: Glad I could help. Sometimes the solution *is* simple :)